# Unix Shell Script to Remove MongoDB Document-Based on Many inputs

Tags: mongodb, unix, sh

Here I am in a position to write a Unix Shell `script(.sh)` to remove MongoDB collection documents.
I know how to remove based on a condition like below and it works for me.

```
eval 'db.Collection.remove({TimeStamp:{$lte: "'$var'"}})
```

But I need to change the remove statement based on a new parameter ,lets say PID which will receive bunch of inputs(Many PID's).

I don't need to remove the collection based on the Timestamp field ,Instead my condition has to be changed as per my previous statement.

I went through many forums ,But I am not able to get the solution.

Please help me to resolve this in my `UNIX` shell script.

Comment: Is like a kill -9 Number_PID?

Comment: My Collection have another attribute called PID ,like Timestamp.Where we will store integer kind of values like 1233,1456,4566..etc .So I require to remove documents who has PID as 1233,1456 in my batch.

Comment: Example {"TimeStamp": "20191230", "PID": 1233}
{"TimeStamp": "20191226", "PID": 1456}
{"TimeStamp": "20191225", "PID": 4566}
{"TimeStamp": "20191226", "PID": 8987}

Comment: When you say "unix shell" do you mean shell mongo....right?

Comment: No.I am saying .sh script as shell script.I am inserting ,updating and removing thru Unix Shell script (.sh)... Example #!/bin/ksh

Comment: I know what is .sh ....but you will put inside your file .sh a shell mongo?

Comment: Yes sir.Inside my .sh file I will connect Mongo shell(with Host:port,Username and password.) to do these insert ,delete operation.